# Change default key action JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace a keystroke with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064707/how-do-i-replace-a-keystroke-with-jquery)

Is there a way where I can change the default character of a key pressed in JavaScript. Like if somebody presses the "E" Button, it will print out a p instead, and this is live, so like its being typed into a textarea. Anyway to do this with jQuery or anything like that? Thnaks!

Comment: @Bryan: While this question is very similar to the linked question, the linked one had no real solution.  This question has a simple solution (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete example of a working solution, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery/2819568#2819568) answer:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    insertAtCaret: function(myValue) {
        return this.each(function(i) {
            if (document.selection) {
                //For browsers like Internet Explorer
                this.focus();
                sel = document.selection.createRange();
                sel.text = myValue;
                this.focus();
            }
            else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
                //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
                var startPos = this.selectionStart;
                var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
                var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
                this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
                this.focus();
                this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
                this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
                this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
            } else {
                this.value += myValue;
                this.focus();
            }
        })
    }
});

$(function() {
    var ta = $('<textarea id="ta" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></textarea>').appendTo('body');
    ta.keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 101) // e
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            ta.insertAtCaret('P');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. However does TA need to be appended to body, or can I use a traditional prexcisitng selecot?

Comment: @JonahAllibone: No need to append; that was just for the demo.  You can use e.g. `var ta = $('#ta');`

Comment: I recently tried doing this, and It didn't work. Nothing happens. It does the normal

Comment: Do you have textarea with `id="ta"` ?  If not, you need to create one.  Please post a fiddle link if you still have trouble.

Comment: I realized that I was assuming this would also work on a contentEditable div, but it appears that the browser treats contentEdiable div selections different from that of textarea selections. If you have a solution for that please post it! haha

Comment: @JonahAllibone: "have a solution"?  Not off-hand, but 1 Google + paste yields: http://jsfiddle.net/D38Jq/ (note linked topic here on StackOverflow).  Only thing missing is updating the caret position.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this framework for adding keyboard shortcuts.

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Of course it won't automatically convert any keypress to another character and output that character, you will have to figure out what part of the page has focus, for instance a text field, and modify it's value with what ever character you actually want to be inputed.